# Can't build 32-bit Perl on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, perl, build, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying build **32-bit** ActivePerl for Windows:

```
call "X:\VC98\Bin\VCVARS32.BAT"
cd "X:\PERL\win32"

set WIN64=undef
nmake
```

On 32-bit Windows everything is OK and I have no warnings and no errors.

But on 64-bit Windows 32-bit build fails:

```
cl -c -nologo -GF -W3 -I..\lib\CORE -I.\include -I. -I.. -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DPERLDLL -DPERL_CORE -MD -Zi -DNDEBUG -O1 -DPERL_EXTERNAL_GLOB -DPERL_IS_MINIPERL -Fo.\mini\doio.obj ..\doio.c
doio.c
..\doio.c(324) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'unsigned __int64 ' to 'int ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(1613) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64 ' to 'long ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(1646) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64 ' to 'long ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(1647) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64 ' to 'long ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(1697) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64 ' to 'long ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(1743) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64 ' to 'long ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(1759) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__int64 ' to 'long ', possible loss of data
..\doio.c(324) : fatal error C1001: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR
```

How to build 32-bit Perl on 64 bit Windows?

Comment: Maybe this should be reported as a bug at the GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues) ?